# Why does Harry Potter need to go to the King's Cross station with a guard at the beginning of his fifth year at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

The morning where Harry attends his fifth year at Hogwarts, why does he need to go to the King's Cross station with a guard? Was it because of Voldemort or was it because of the Death Eaters?

Comment: This is a particularly interesting question because at that point in the story, the Ministry denies the existence of both.

Comment: @F1Krazy wasn't the guard provided by the Order? As in, it's not the Ministry providing the guard, so why would it be odd? (People are free to come along with students without justification aren't they?)

Comment: @Jenayah I didn't remember, and the question didn't specify.

Answer (score 6):

### The guard was provided by the Order

Although after the events in *GoF*, the Ministry completely disregarded the presence of Death Eaters and the return of Voldemort, the Order of the Phoenix took Harry's and Dumbledore's word for it. Therefore, they were always prepared to protect Harry.

This was also the reason why Dumbledore put Mrs. Figg and Mundungus Fletecher to keep an eye on Harry.

> “Why didn’t you tell me you’re a Squib?” Harry asked Mrs. Figg,
> panting with the effort to keep walking.
> “All those times I came round
> your house — why didn’t you say anything?”
>
> “Dumbledore’s orders. I was
> to keep an eye on you but not say anything, you were too young. I’m
> sorry I gave you such a miserable time, but the Dursleys would never
> have let you come if they’d thought you enjoyed it. It wasn’t easy,
> you know. . . . But oh my word,” she said tragically, wringing her
> hands once more, “when Dumbledore hears about this — how could
> Mundungus have left, he was supposed to be on duty until midnight —
> where is he? How am I going to tell Dumbledore what’s happened, I
> can’t Apparate —”
>
> <sub>Excerpt: *Harry Potter and The Order of the Phoenix: Chapter 2(A Deck of Owls)*</sub>

Additionally, in Chapter Ten, Hermione tells it was Mad-Eye Moody who put the guards on Harry.

> “Mrs. Weasley’s patched her up,” said Hermione. “But now Mad- Eye’s
> complaining that we can’t leave unless Sturgis Podmore’s here,
> otherwise the guard will be one short.”
>
> “Guard?” said Harry.
>
> “We have to go to King’s Cross with a guard?”
>
> “You have to go to King’s Cross with a guard,” Hermione corrected him.
>
> “Why?” said Harry irritably. “I thought Voldemort was supposed to be lying low, or are you telling me he’s going to jump out from behind a dustbin to try and do me in?”
>
> “I don’t know, it’s just what Mad-Eye says,” said Hermione distractedly, looking at her watch.
>
> “But if we don’t leave soon we’re definitely going to miss the train. . . .”
>
> <sub>Excerpt: *Harry Potter and The Order of the Phoenix: Chapter 10 (Luna Lovegood)*</sub>

Thus both Dumbledore and the Order decided to keep an eye on Harry all the time until he reached Hogwarts. After that, Dumbledore as well as the staff would be there to keep him safe.

As for why they needed so many guards to protect Harry at King's Cross, well, Mad-Eye decided that. After all he was locked in a box for a year by a Death Eater (who was presumed dead) and his history from his Auror times led to this [paranoia] perhaps.

To quote Mad-Eye,

> *Constant vigilance!*

Comment: That answers who provided the guard, but not why.

Answer (score 0):

The guard was provided by the Order, precisely because they know Voldemort has returned and he or his Death Eaters might try to attack Harry on the way to King's Cross.

Comment: Whilst a nice answer could you [edit] in some evidence for this to back it up?

Comment: Shreedhar already provided the evidence. I'll remember to add some in my next answers!